# Что означают цифры и аббревиатура после "Quattro Fontane"?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

> Палаццо Барберини. Национальная галерея старинного искусства. Via
>   delle Quattro Fontane, 13, 00184 Roma RM.

Если 00184 индекс, то... зачем он? Не письма же по нему писать? О_о

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Формат итальянского почтового адреса:

> улица - номер дома по ней - почтовый индекс - город - код провинции

(здесь "Ул. 4-х фонтанов")

http://www.bitboost.com/ref/international-address-formats/italy/

Comment: Спасибо, Саша! Код провинции потряс меня до глубины души... Это как я не знала, что живу в провинции Московская область, обитая в центре столицы городе Москве!

Comment: Если бы нас туда присоединили, был бы код МО субъекта Федерации :)

Comment: Кстати, надо же как-то не спутать ту, что в МО, с Moscow TN и ещё с 19 такими в Штатах...